# LINQ filter LIST values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have LINQ query

```
Label = c.Name.Translations.Select(label => new Label
                {                        
                    Rus = label.Text,
                    Eng = label.Text,
                }),
```

Translation class

```
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Text { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }



  public class Translation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

which return list like this

```
{
"rus":"Нью-Йорк",
"eng":"Нью-Йорк"
},
{
"rus":"New-York",
"eng":"New-York"
```

My goal is have one item like this

```
"rus":"Нью-Йорк",
"eng":"New-York"
```

How can i filter it ?

Comment: you want to select only first item?

Comment: In other word i want to merge two items with appropriate values.

Comment: Can you show us the `Translation` class?

Comment: It might be useful to explain why you set them both to the same value in the first place? There's a chance you can achieve what you want without a second pass.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Just a sidenote, but why the hardcoding of the languages in `Label`?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand this question. It would be nice if you specify what exactly are you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
var labels = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var item in c.Name.Translations)
{
    labels.add(item.Language, item.Text);
}
```

*Edit*

```
var labels = c.Name.Translations.ToDictionary(t => t.Language, t => t.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var label = c.Name.Translations.ToDictionary(translation => translation.Language, translation => translation.Text);
```

This creates a dictionary which can be accessed in the following way

```
label["eng"] // This returns "New York"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by a LINQ query for each of your `Label` class property:

```
var resultLabel = new Label
{
    Eng = Translations.FirstOrDefault(trans => trans.Language == "English")?.Text,
    Rus = Translations.FirstOrDefault(trans => trans.Language == "Russian")?.Text,
};
```

Comment: This works, but iterates the collection twice. Ideally it uses Linq grouping so the list is iterated just once, unless performance is not important here, in which case this solution is short and sweet.

Comment: @MarkCiliaVincenti if you are looking for a `Label` object as a solution, I don‍‍'t see any better way. but if you want the same functionality and not necessarily a ‍‍‍`Label` object, `Siavash` answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> langText = new Dictionary<string, string>();
c.Name.Translations.ForEach(x => langText.Add(x.Language, x.Text));
```

langText will contain your data.

Comment: I basically shared the same thing earlier in my answer